# How to define a default initial file in vim given the file extension?

Tags: vim

Everytime I write a new python program, I find myself writing the same initial lines over and over again:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
Description of the program
'''
import always, the, same, libraries

def helper_function(helpers_args):
'''
A function that is called in get_main_output, but that someone might want to import too.
'''
    continue

def get_main_output(program_arguments):
'''
Description of the main function
'''
    continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    output = get_main_output(sys.argv)
```

I don't want to have to do it by hand everytime. I would like vim to show me this file everytime I open a nonexistent file with the extension `.py`, so that I can modify it as needed and then save it to my newly created source file.

How can I achieve this?

Apologies if the answer is already somewhere. I thought it would be, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: each new py file you want those stuff? like `if __name__ == '__main__'`?

Comment: No, OP need the whole skeleton script (check my answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### In `/etc/vim/vimrc` or `/etc/vimrc` or `~/.vimrc`

```
" python skeleton
autocmd BufNewFile *.py 0r ~/.vim/skeleton.py
```

### skeleton file:

```
~/.vim/skeleton.py
```

Put the python code from your original post inside this file as *simple-user*

### Vim documentation:

[`skeleton`/`template`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#skeleton) within [`autocmd.txt`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html)

Comment: Works great! Just one thing - it works for me only if the 2 lines are added to ~/.vimrc, not to ~/.vim/vimrc. You might want to mention that too.

Comment: @FerdinandoRandisi Yes, it should be `~/.vimrc`. `~/.vim/vimrc` will only work if you make `vimrc` and `gvimrc` symlinks to files within `~/.vim/` using `ln -s ~/.vim/vimrc ~/.vimrc` and `ln -s ~/.vim/gvimrc ~/.gvimrc`. Such symlinking can keep your Vim configuration more organized.

Comment: Note, `~/.vim/vimrc` is automatically sourced by Vim if no `~/.vimrc` exists since 7.3.1178